# Does the community want the accepted answers to be pinned to the top?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Stack Exchange staffs [recently announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers?cb=1) that they are considering the prospect of unpinning the accepted answer from the top of answers and instead sort them by votes. I noticed some of the other communities discussing this on their meta sites, so I thought of initiating a discussion on Anime & Manga Meta too.

This setting will be configurable per site. The default setting will be fixed according to the preference of the majority among the Stack Exchange Network. The staffs requested to discuss this question within individual communities and they are going to collect the feedback before the end of September 19th.

**Does the Anime and Manga community want the accepted answer to be unpinned, or to stay pinned as it currently is?**

Comment: Supplementary data: [Questions whose accepted answer is outscored by another answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1457743/questions-whose-accepted-answer-is-outscored-by-another-answer#resultSets) (as of now: 225 questions)

Comment: id say yes, should i elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ it'd be great if you could elaborate it in an answer so that the community can understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say let it be unpinned.

Quite frankly, if there is more than one answer on a question, especially on something like Anime or Manga, I would honestly say that it's fine to let other answers that the community thinks are better float to the top as opposed to the one that the OP thought was best at the time.

Comment: Devils advocate; why hasn't [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/55600) floated to the top following your argument?

Comment: The older answer attracted more attention from the people who were active at the time, @Peilonrayz.  To be fair the accepted answer is quite good and well-detailed, but there aren't as many people around actively upvoting this kind of content.  This is an important canary to indicate as well, in my assessment.